# unable to abort queued scheduled job

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, custom-controller

I have an apex job scheduled by mistake and now I cannot able to delete that. Due to that, I cannot able to edit my existing apex class. I tried the steps from Salesforce.com artice and when I execute `system.abortjob('jobid')` from Apex execute in workbench, I am getting following error

> COMPILE ERROR: Unexpected token '('.
>   LINE: 1 COLUMN: 16

Can anyone suggest is there any other approach so that I can abort the queued job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgotten the `;` in the code on the end of the line. If you change your code to this, it will work:

```java
System.abortJob('jobid');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some mistakes in your abort code, but i think you can delete your scheduler job in setup->Scheduled Jobs.